# Creating and writing to a log file using morgan in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am trying to create a log file if it doesn't exist, and if it does exist then I want morgan to write the logs to it. Here is the code

```
  // Function to write a file in a non-existing directory
  function writeFile(path, contents, cb){
    mkdirp(getDirName(path), function(err){
      if (err) return cb(err);
      fs.writeFile(path, contents, cb);
    });
  }

  // Check if log file exists, if it does not, then create it
  fs.exists(__dirname + '/log/access.log', function(exists){
    if(exists){
      app.use(logger('common', {
        stream: fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/log/access.log', {flags: 'a'})
      }));
      console.log('access.log exists!');
    } else {
      writeFile(__dirname + '/log/access.log', {flag: 'wx'}, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('access.log created!');
      });
    }
  });
```

The first function creates the log directory and access.log file. The problem is when I hit a route it doesn't log anything to access.log. It was working before when the app.use call was not in fs.exists so I don't know if thats the problem or not, but when It's not in fs.exists it will error out due to the file not having been created yet.

Comment: fs.exists is asynchronous, it's likely that by the time it runs, the middleware is being added so far down the line that it isn't catching the requests before they are ended.

Comment: Additionally, if it doesn't exist it creates it, but never attaches the middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `fs.existsSync`. The reason being that the `app.use` call is executing further down the event loop due to the asynchronous call to `fs.exists`. My guess is that by the time the `fs.exists` callback is invoked, your express app is already configured and has begun listening. Try this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var logPath = path.join(__dirname, 'log', 'access.log');

if (fs.existsSync(logPath)) {
  app.use(logger('common', {
    stream: fs.createWriteStream(logPath, {flags:'a'});
  }));
  console.log('access.log exists!');
} else {
  fs.mkdirSync(path.dirname(logPath));
  fs.writeFileSync(logPath, {flags:'wx'});
  console.log('access.log created!');
}
```

Since this appears to be code that runs during application startup, making it synchronous shouldn't be very costly. I'm sure you could make the asynchronous setup work by restructuring how your express app and all it's middleware is constructed, but it won't save you much since these operations clearly need to happen in order before `app.listen` anyway.

Comment: I have created a logger using winston , morgan and daily rotate file. The problem is that if i save the code only the log folder and files are generated. if i try to hit the route the folder is not creating basically http req is taken care of morgan but eventhough i combined it it is not working any idea on this issue